# Planet Orbiting a Red Dwarf

Tags: planets, stars, solar-system, habitability, life

I'm trying to create my planet orbiting a red dwarf, honestly I've thought other scenarios but it's like every answer opens new questions. I'll just say what I want my planet to be and I'd like your help(please) to understand how it would work.

I'm new with worldbuilding(started yesterday), so bear with my lack of knowledge, if you don't want to use your time answering, I'd like research sources too.

I want the flora to be mainly black, so the sunlight has to be somewhat weaker, which would make the planet(or the habitable zone) fairly cold.

The planet being tidally locked seems to be the common, and I don't mind, apparently the habitable zone would be the ring around the planet between the parts that do and don't face the star, but I don't know if such a thing is entirely possible, what are the complications the inhabitants of such a planet face?

Apparently it *doesn't* have to be tidally locked, but I didn't understand how that works, apparently it would have to have some kind of moon orbiting around it?

If you want to show off your knowledge and tell me how the sky would appear...I'll be impressed.

If it needs something unlikely to happen for desired situations I don't mind either, the planet was somewhat "made" by "gods".

Yes, sorry, I don't know much, whoever gives the time to answer, know that I'm grateful.

Comment: Your flora would in all likelihood appear dark blue green (cyan). Because the flora would evolve to absorb red light. A red dwarf is a small star. Your planet would be small. It would be much closer to the star than we are. Think Mercury.. it would therefore have a thinner atmosphere.. with a reddish hue.

Comment: @Richard "Your planet would be small" - why?

Comment: To be in the habitable zone of a red dwarf it would need to be in close orbit. A large rocky planet in such close orbit seems unlikely... It's not impossible (at least I don't think it is) but my understanding is that it is always smaller planets that orbit closest.

Comment: @Richard You mean like how Mars is bigger than Earth? Seriously it is much more complex than that. As in, it is pretty hard to be provably wrong when deciding your planet size unless you decide to develop and share an absolutely insane amount of useless astronomical data. Just to be clear your thinking is not really wrong, real world star systems are just too complex for it to be a practical issue for most world building. And honestly with a red dwarf star I am not sure if we (as a species) actually know enough to build a fully realistic system with any confidence.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Heck, even within our own system, there's so much we're still learning. Though to you last point, I prefer to think of it in an positive light: almost anything could be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Worldbuilding!

First, the planet itself **does not** need to be tidally locked.  **Either scenario is plausible.**  It depends on the history of the planet's formation.  Even Mercury itself isn't tidally locked.  So, it's up to you.

If you do decide you want your planet to be tidally locked, then:

- It can have a moon, but the orbit of said moon would be at risk of destabilizing over a very, *very* long period of time.  Eventually it could fall into the planet, opposite of what is happening with our own moon right now.  (Potential plot point?)
- The climate of a tidally-locked planet's habitable zone may be [wildly unstable](https://www.space.com/13950-habitable-alien-planets-tidal-lock-life.html).  However, this mainly depends on a) the composition of the atmosphere and surface rock, and b) the surface conditions at the subsolar point, especially vis-a-vis liquid water.  I can elaborate on this with more information on your planet's environment.

As far as size goes (regardless of whether it's tidally locked), the planet can be very small, like Mercury, or several times larger than the Earth.  Again, it's up to you.  Scientists have found *massive* rocky planets closer to their parent stars than the Earth is to the Sun.  [Here's a recently discovered example](https://phys.org/news/2018-11-astronomers-super-earth-barnard-star.html) of one such planet.

As for the flora:  [According to this source](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/04/110419-alien-trees-black-plants-planets-ras-space-science/), you might expect the color of flora to naturally appear "red, blue, yellow, purple, or even grayish-black."  Interestingly, that article mainly discusses planets orbiting binary stars, postulating their flora might appear black to us.  In any case, it depends on the amount of light the plants receive and their chemical make-up.  I would wager that dark-ish blue, purple, and gray colors would be more than acceptable, though I would recommend against having one single uniform color throughout the entire world.  (Keep in mind the vast variety of plant life colors here on Earth, for comparison.)

Finally, the appearance of the sky depends on a lot of things, including (but not limited to) the composition of the gases in the atmosphere, dust in the air, distance from the star, etc.  I'll gladly edit my answer if you provide more details in your question.  Or, if you already have in mind a particular way you want the sky to look, I can attempt to give you conditions that might produce it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really, and sorry for not replying sooner, I couldn't get the account back easily, and honestly I didn't think this community was so active, 
I'm very glad it is.

Comment: About your answer: It doesn't need to be tidally locked, so if it's such a problem, I won't do it. I thought black because I was imagining they receiving less light from the sun, and of course, not all will be black, just most of them and not jet black too, just black-ish. https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/blackbody-spectrum/blackbody-spectrum_pt_BR.html a red sky seems good, not sure about sunset though. And how would be the night and day system? could it be similar to Earth's? How would the moon be? Again, thank you.

Comment: @Guy You're very welcome. Whether it's tidally locked is up to you; either way is possible so go with whatever you prefer. If the planet is not tidally locked, and you want a system similar to Earth's with a similar sized moon, then go right ahead. The main difference will be how quickly the planet orbits and rotates. If you tell me how long you want your days and years to last, we could come up with a reasonable estimation.

Comment: @Guy Second, sorry if I wasn't clear on plant colors. Here on Earth, the chemical makeup of a plant determines what parts of the spectrum get absorbed. I'm not botany expert, but from what I do know, I see no reason at this point why your plants couldn't have evolved to absorb light in a way that makes them appear black.

Comment: @Guy Oh, and if you do want your planet to be tidally locked, then you would likely be inhabiting a thin band around the planet. (Tidal locking severely limits the habitable area of the surface, since one side is always *really* hot and the other is *really* cold.) So, you would be in perpetual twilight, all day every day. On the "near" side, *maybe* you could go far enough south so that you'd just barely see the sun peeking up over the horizon; it would look like a sunrise that was frozen in place.

Comment: I see, I understand it being tidally locked is possible, but the complications of it is the climate instability, I don't plan on explaining this to them, I just want to understand, If it's possible to be tidally locked how would be the climate of the habitable zone? And they won't leave the habitable "ring" around the planet, so I won't worry about the land outside there, for now. Thanks.

Comment: @Guy As I understand the weather pattern models, the general consensus is that if the area of your planet directly facing the star is an ocean, then severe weather can be avoided. If that's not possible, then assuming an Earth-like atmosphere (primarily nitrogen), you still might be ok; it still wouldn't necessarily develop runaway heating problems (producing crazy winds) or catastrophic greenhouse effects (causing surface temps to be too high for liquid water). If your atmosphere was primarily some other gas(es), it could be a different story. (Con't)

Comment: @Guy (Con't) The light side of the planet would still be really hot, and there'd still be some pretty gusty winds blowing (primarily) from the light side to the dark side, but nothing that would necessarily make it unliveable. As a side note, if you have an ocean that occupies both sides, the dark side doesn't need to be completely frozen due to warmer currents. But an ocean completely on the dark side would probably be largely, if not entirely, frozen.

Comment: A large ocean on both sides actually was what I wanted, I can't imagine how crazy would be the winds, but I can think of alternatives. Thanks for sticking with me for this long, I appreciate it .

Comment: @Guy If you do have a large ocean, then you'll be fine with the winds. In general it might be more gusty more of the time than here on Earth, and they'll have some rough storms to deal with, but nothing they couldn't handle. Maybe a "refreshing" summer breeze for them entails 30 mph/50 kph wind speeds. (Picture something like here on Earth when tropical storms pass nearby. It's not as though you can't still walk around outside or anything.) If this is a space-faring civilization, then they probably have the technology (and the determination) to put up with some gusty winds, right?

Comment: They do, it shouldn't be a problem. I said it many times already, but thank you very much, english isn't my first language and this is going to be my first story, so it will most likely be really bad and no one(except my friend) will read it, but as bill wurtz said in his "long long long journey" song "If I came here to lose, then I still might win."                                                                                  Wish you the best.

Comment: @Hans You're very welcome, and good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

"What are the complications the inhabitants of such a planet face?"

Well, since the planet is tidally locked (and as long as it's been so for at least thousands of years), the sunny side would likely experience tropical temperatures year-round, or even hotter. and would be mostly overtaken by an ocean with small archipelagos scattered around.

The vegetation on a brighter side might evolve to be whiter, as it doesn't require that much sun to grow and thus needs to bounce some away. The opposite could be true for the dark side, although plants would likely not even exist at all and might be completely overtaken by a massive ice sheet.

Since there are virtually no seasons or things of the like, animals wouldn't migrate, weather would be extremely predictable, and farms would be widespread and easy to grow. Life on the bright side would evolve quickly, while those on the dark side would likely die out quickly.

---

"Apparently it doesn't have to be tidally locked, but I didn't understand how that works, apparently it would have to have some kind of moon orbiting around it?"

I can't really see how that'd be true. Since the planet would have to be really close to the red dwarf (since the star is small and thus has a closer habitable zone), the tidal forces acting on the planet would be much stronger than Earth's and would pretty much force it into being tidally locked.

---

"If you want to show off your knowledge and tell me how the sky would appear...I'll be impressed."

The appearance of the sky essentially depends on how dense the planet's atmosphere is. Earth's is blue because of the high amounts of gases. The gas particles completely absorb most short-wavelength colors, like blue, which scatters them (basically radiating blue out in all directions from the particle). Since blue is one of the most scattered colors, the sky appears blue because blue light is constantly hitting the gas particles.

It could also depend on the range of colors emitted by the star. The Sun would appear white if you were to be suspended in space without the atmosphere to color it, and so it emits virtually all light on the color spectrum. If the star emits only reds and oranges, the atmosphere would be predisposed to being in that range.

I don't know how dense your planet's atmosphere is, but the less dense it is, the darker and fainter it would be. Since it orbits a red dwarf, the sky would likely be orange or even yellow.

---

Comment: This description doesn't jive with our best models. In all likelihood, the sunny side would be so hot that it's questionable whether there'd be surface water on that side whatsoever. As for tidal locking, it's not a given that it would be locked (it's possible, of course, but not a certainty). Also, the weather could in fact be extremely **un**predictable, depending. Lastly, the plant colors you laid out are probably backwards. (I posted links about those last two points in my answer you might find interesting.)

Comment: All that said, I don't want to sound so negative. Your points about the atmosphere are good. But your description of the surface is unfortunately too picturesque according to the best models we have today. But in spite of that, anything is possible. It's interesting to try and conceive plausible conditions for the environment you've described, perhaps something on the outer fringes of the Goldilocks zone with particularly favorable atmospheric and landscape characteristics of some sort which we haven't generally accounted for....

Comment: Thanks. I thought some of the points seemed off, but most of them were taken from a science-based website (although I can't remember the URL). The plant colors made sense to me simply because it's a commonly-known fact that white reflects more sunlight while black absorbs more, but I can definitely see your point.

Comment: Yeah, the plant thing totally seemed counterintuitive at first to me, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, If tidally locked, I wanted them to be in a cold environment, which give me 2 options, either putting the planet a bit farther away from the star, or moving their living place a bit closer to the dark side, the first seems more complicated(or not?), I thought black because I was considering moving the planet, and in my logic, somehow, the light reaching the plants would be fainter and the habitable zone would be colder, making the plants darker to absorb more light, does it make sense?